# When is a function on symmetric positive definite matrices an expectation of Gaussian?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, real-analysis

Is there some characterization of real-valued functions of the form $\Phi(C)=\mathbb{E}F(X)$, where $X$ has the Gaussian $N(0,C)$ distribution, on the space of symmetric positive semidefinite $n\times n$ matrices $C$? In other words, given $\Phi\colon \mathrm{SPD}\to \mathbb{R}$, is there a way to tell whether such $F$ exists?

**Edit:** For example, is it clear that $\det(C)$ is not of this form?

**Edit 2:** Answer below shows that $\det(C)$ is not of this form even for $n=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach to determine if $\det(C)$ is of this form with $F$ analytic and $n=2$.

By Sylvester's criterion a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a& b \\ b & c\end{pmatrix}$ is symmetric positive semidefinite iff $a\ge 0$ and $c\ge 0$, and $ac-b^2\ge 0$.

Let $X=(X_1,X_2)$ be normal with mean 0 and $E(X_1X_2)=b$, $E(X_1^2)=a$, $E(X_2^2)=c$.
The Pearson correlation coefficient is $\rho=b/\sqrt{ac}$.
Suppose $F(x,y)=\sum c_{mn}x^my^n$.

Is there an $F$ with $E(F(X))=ac-b^2$?
We [have](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_2_bivariate_normal_dist.php) $X=\sqrt{a}Z_1$, $Y=\sqrt{c}(\rho Z_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2)$ where $Z_i$ are independent standard normal, so
using
$$E\left[(\rho Z_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2)^{2k}\right]=E\sum_{t=0}^{2k}\binom{2k}{t}\rho^t(1-\rho^2)^{(2k-t)/2}Z_1^t Z_2^{2k-t}$$
$$=\sum_{t=0}^{2k}\binom{2k}{t}\rho^t(1-\rho^2)^{(2k-t)/2}E[Z_1^t Z_2^{2k-t}]
=\sum_{u=0}^{k}\binom{2k}{2u}\rho^{2u}(1-\rho^2)^{(2k-2u)/2}E[Z_1^{2u} Z_2^{2k-2u}]$$
$$=\sum_{u=0}^{k}\binom{2k}{2u}\rho^{2u}(1-\rho^2)^{(2k-2u)/2}(2u-1)!!(2(k-u)-1)!!$$
(where $(-1)!!=1$)
we have
$$E(X^{2\ell}Y^{2k})=a^\ell c^k\sum_{u=0}^{k}\binom{2k}{2u}\rho^{2u}(1-\rho^2)^{k-u}(2(\ell+u)-1)!!(2(k-u)-1)!!$$

- When $k=\ell=1$, it is $ac((1-\rho^2)+3\rho^2)=ac+2b^2$
  since $\rho^2=b^2/ac$.
- When $k=0$ and $\ell=2$, it is $3a^2$.
- When $k=2$ and $\ell=0$, it is $3c^2-4b^4/a^2$.
- I guess we should also do the case $E(X^3Y^1)$ and a couple of others.

A Taylor series in variables $a,b,c$ defines the zero function only if all coefficients are zero.
So now by calculating these expectations $E(X^pY^q)$ we can determine whether
$ac-b^2$ is obtainable.

Comment: Thank you, good idea. Only fourth order polynomials in $(X,Y)$ will give second order polynomials in $(a,b,c)$ so together with $\mathbb{E}X^3 Y=3ab$ your observations above means that such analytic $F$ does not exist. I think this also means that such non-analytic $F$ does not exist either, because otherwise $\det(C+I)=\mathbb{E} F(X+z_1,Y+z_2) = \mathbb{E}\tilde F(X,Y)$ where $\tilde F$ is now analytic but $\det(C+I)=ac-b^2+a+c$ has the same second order terms. So $\det$ is not of this form then.

Comment: @D_809 Can you explain how you get $\tilde F$?

Comment: $\tilde F(x,y) = \mathbb{E}F(x+z_1,y+z_2)$ where $(z_1,z_2)$ is standard Gaussian. In the above comment $(X,Y)$ was your $(X_1,X_2)$ and $(z_1,z_2)$ was independent of $(X,Y)$. By the way, this result gives the identities faster: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem (I can not write @ your name for some reason).

Comment: Great. Well, you automatically notify the author when you comment on their answer.